# Compile issue with GWT back end in libgdx

Tags: gwt, libgdx

It compiled fine a few days ago but something i did must have caused the issue but so much was done i am not too sure.

Error log here: http://pastebin.com/P1JHqDBD

If anyone needs anything else to solve the issue, let me know!

I tried deleting the unitcache folder in my HTML5 folder. didnt help, same isse. also tried cleaning.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
    Nov 27, 2013 10:31:12 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[ERROR] Failure in unit cache map load.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.awaitUnitCacheMapLoad(PersistentUnitCache.java:466)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.find(PersistentUnitCache.java:391)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.addArchive(CompilationStateBuilder.java:365)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.ArchivePreloader.preloadArchives(ArchivePreloader.java:65)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:106)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte cache
        at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:171)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.readObject(DiskCacheToken.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.readObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:204)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.loadUnitMap(PersistentUnitCache.java:517)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache.access$800(PersistentUnitCache.java:96)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$4.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected EOF in middle of data block
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.refill(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferFromStream(DiskCache.java:159)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Can you please post stacktrace here? I'm not able to access the link.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what i did, i tried removing the war folder and put it back and suddenly it worked ....no idea :/